# How to handle 'Keep' and 'Discard' option while download files in chrome in selenium without AutoIt?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium ver. 2.47 and Chrome Ver. 70

**I have tried with below code but it didn't worked.**

```
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
options.addArguments("--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection");
prefs.put("safebrowsing.enabled", "false");
```

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Hi Peter,
I'm stuck on exactly the same point you describe. Did you achieve the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Seems you were pretty close. You need to pass the *HashMap* containing the required configurations to the instance of the *ChromeOptions* Class as follows:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe");
HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
chromePrefs.put("safebrowsing.enabled", "true"); //this is the needed configuration
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: I have tried above code but it still shows Keep and Discard options.